# Fancybox 2 Title "Inside" on YouTube (iframe)?

Tags: fancybox-2

Is it possible to put the title "inside" when using Fancybox 2 for YouTube/iFrame content?
Anytime I try to insert

```
title: {
    type: 'inside'
}
```

the video then plays in a new window at full screen.
Here is what I'm currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".vids").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '60%',
            height      : '60%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
      });
  });
</script>
```

As a bonus, I would like the Title text to contain a link that opens `_blank` if it's possible.

Also, perhaps related, to make videos play in all browsers, I have to alter the YouTube links, rather than doing something like:

```
<a class="vids fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whatever">
```

I have to change it, and insert the word "embed", such as:

```
<a class="vids fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/whatever">
```

Is this a proper method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many question eh?

**First**, to get the `title` inside the fancybox use the option `helpers` like

```
helpers: {  title : { type : 'inside' } }
```

**Second**, to set a `title` with a link ... I would advice to you to set a `data-*` attribute in your anchor so the link won't show up in the normal browser's tooltip ... something like

```
<a class="vids" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whatever" title="normal title" data-caption="<a href='{new link}' >See more</a>">open video</a>
```

**Notice** that I didn't add `target="_blank"` since clicking on the link will navigate automatically to the next page (and closing fancybox)

Then use the callback `beforeShow` to construct the `title`

```
beforeShow: function(){
 this.title = this.title + " " + $(this.element).data("caption");
}
```

**Third**, the proper way to display youtube videos is having a normal link (like in me second example above) and no more. Then include the *fancybox-media* js file in your document like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

(check your own path)

... and use the `helpers` option to set the media like

```
helpers : {media : {} }
```

so, **summarizing**, your html should be something like

```
<a class="vids" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whatever" title="normal title" data-caption="<a href='{new link}' >See more</a>">open video</a>
```

and your fancybox custom script like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".vids").fancybox({
  maxWidth    : 800,
  maxHeight   : 600,
  fitToView   : false,
  width       : '60%',
  height      : '60%',
  autoSize    : false,
  closeClick  : false,
  openEffect  : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none',
  helpers     : {  
        title : { type : 'inside' },
        media : {}
  },
  beforeShow: function(){
   this.title = this.title + " " + $(this.element).data("caption");
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I made a few changes, down sized the player, and decided against the link within the title. All is good except...in my html, I'm still having to edit as the prior example, with the word "embed". Using the direct link as you gave, Newest versions of FF/Chrome/Safari just show either the animated loading gif, or blank white. IE9 will say"

"This content cannot be displayed in a frame
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."